# Regular expression to remove duplicate charcters and replace charcters in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle11g

Can any one provide me single regular expression to remove duplicate characters and replace characters.

Example:

Input: `'ABACB'`

Here I need to remove duplicates and I need to replace `A` with `X` and `B` with `Y` and `C` with `Z`

So output should be `XYZ`

Comment: I doubt you can do that in one step. Replacing `(\w)(?=.*\1)` with empty `''` (globally) will remove all duplicates though.

Comment: i used your regular expression.select regexp_replace('aa', '(\w)(?=.*\1)', '') from dual.But output is aa.Expected output is a

Comment: Yes...? It appears as if Oracle doesn't support look-aheads. So it won't work :(

Comment: i tried this select regexp_replace('bbaa', '(.)\1+', '\1') from dual.Here if the input is like aabb out put is ab.But if the input is abab out put is abab.But expected output is ab

Comment: You could try `regexp_replace('ABACB', '((\w).*?)\2', '\1', 1, 0)`.

Comment: its failed with this string. select regexp_replace('AAAABBBB', '((\w).*?)\2', '\1', 1, 0) from dual.Output is AABB but expected is AB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117214/discussion-between-vissu-and-clasg).